# Can I send myself push notifications from a server without making my own Android app?

Tags: notifications, push-notifications

I am making a chat box on my website that sends the text to the server which forwards it to my phone as a push notification. The problem is I have basically zero Android or Java programming skills. However, I'm familiar with how to send GCM notifications from the server. I think if I only had the device ID (and possibly a way to subscribe to the messages?) I'd be fine.

Do I need to do any Android programming? Is there a way to receive custom messages without making a new app? Or an app that already exists to do this?

Comment: You mean android device id? If thats the case you may want to check device id apps in playstore

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I have to double check, but I need to be able to send myself push notifications from a server. Hopefully the device id is all that's required.

Comment: I am not really sure with GCM prerequisites, but a source mentions you need Sender ID, I am not sure if that's the DeviceID or Application ID, but do you want to create an app for this? If you simply want device id  then I could probably write a way of doing this in answers section

Comment: I want a way to receive custom notifications from my server on my own device. Seeing if there's a way I can do this without programming an Android app myself, or there's an open-source app I can use.

Comment: I reckon you need to use a service called firebase and link with your android app ,a few guides for this have been prepared online. Also please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12560639

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I don't have a android app lol. But thanks anyway.